# System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In order to retrieve some information of the target machine, I am using following code:

```
 ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_Processor");
 string collectedInfo = ""; // here we will put the informa

 foreach (ManagementObject share in searcher.Get())
 {
     // first of all, the processorid
     collectedInfo += share.GetPropertyValue("ProcessorId").ToString ();
 }

 searcher.Query = new ObjectQuery("select * from Win32_BIOS");
 foreach (ManagementObject share in searcher.Get())
 {
     //then, the serial number of BIOS
     collectedInfo +=share.GetPropertyValue("SerialNumber").ToString ();
 }

 searcher.Query = new ObjectQuery("select * from Win32_BaseBoard");
 foreach (ManagementObject share in searcher.Get())
 {
     //finally, the serial number of motherboard
     collectedInfo+= share.GetPropertyValue("SerialNumber").ToString();
 }
```

This works fine while it is executed as a asp.net website on my local computer, but as I publish it on another web server, it shows a different number.
Is there a way to make it calculate the users information, instead of calculating it for a server?

Comment: As far as I can see, you are retrieving HARDWARE information from the current machine. It is only normal that you get different result on another machine. What kind of `user` information do you want to retrieve?

Comment: This code is executed on a server, however, I would like to get the hardware information of the computer that is browsing the page, if possible.

Comment: Well, you could start from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389290.aspx but I think that the effort required will be very high

Comment: Is there a way to access ManagementObjectSearcher using Silverlight?